# Using spaces in website name at title tags

Tags: seo, title

Let's say I have a domain `rentleasecars.com` or something like that.

Therefore I can use titles like these:

```
Random Page Title | RentLeaseCars
```

```
Random Page Title | Rent & Lease Cars
```

Which one is the better for SEO?

My pick would be the first one becaue it looks more like a brand name, but I'm really curious, because on the other hand the second version covers the keywords more clearly. I know domains with keywords are not working nowadays, but I would be happy to know if there is any difference or Google exactly knows if a word contains more words so it's totally indifferent.

Or one of the two would be treated better?

Comment: These questions have been asked here many many many times before. Do what is right for your users first. Otherwise, it does not matter. Why? Google has cracked this nut decades ago. However, if you were to ask me, I would say option 2. Why? Because anytime you use full language the better. For the record, Google has never been about keywords. Ever! Despite all the SEO B.S. It is about whole language. So use whole language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61335/discussion-between-stephen-ostermiller-and-closetnoc).

Comment: For what it is worth, Google uses nGram analysis to split your RentLeaseCars into Rent, Lease, and Cars. However, I am always about using whole language because sentences return better results. Why? Because more understanding can be gleaned from sentences as opposed to a simple list of terms. I always ask myself what about ?? What about rent lease cars? Rent or lease the car of your choice in all major markets. Or... Rent or lease our junk cars as redneck yard art to impress your friends or irritate your neighbors. ;-)

Comment: The exception is for branding. That is another story for another day. Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

As being a SEO expert I can say that you must use "Random Page Title | Rent & Lease Cars." Because the title has a meaning that let the user know what is the page or website about.